# POST request in React in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

So Im trying to POST multiple times, since in my database Workout has many exercises and on the Workout Volume table every exercise from the Workout table has it's own sets, reps, weight. With this method I can only POST once and then I get an error. How can I POST request multiple times, with one click from the user?

```js
const onSubmit =  (data) => {
//POST request on workout table
        ...
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}/workouts`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(async() => {
        //post request on Workout-Volume table
            let requests = [];
            
        //some logic to split all the entered values into an arrays
            const submittedSets = inputFields.map(exercise => exercise.sets.split(','))
            const submittedReps = inputFields.map(exercise => exercise.reps.split(','))
            const submittedWeight = inputFields.map(exercise => exercise.weight.split(','))

            for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
                
                data.workout_id = data.id
                data.exercise_id = exercises.find(exercise => exercise.exercise_name === submittedExercises[i].toString()).id
                data.sets = submittedSets[i]
                data.reps = submittedReps[i]
                data.weight = submittedWeight[i]
                console.log(data.exercise_id)

                requests.push(
                    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/workout-volume`, {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    }).then(async (response) => {
                        const body = await response.text();
                        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
                        return Promise.resolve(true);
                    }).catch((e)=>{
                        console.error('there was an error:', e.message)
                        return Promise.resolve(false);
                    })
                )
            }
            await Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
                console.log('done')
    
                //     navigate('/workouts')
            })
        })
    }
```

What I get:

```js
there was an error:
overrideMethod  @   react_devtools_backend.js:3973
(anonymous) @   useFormAddWorkout.js:184
Promise.catch (async)       
(anonymous) @   useFormAddWorkout.js:182
Promise.then (async)        
onSubmit    @   useFormAddWorkout.js:153
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:40851
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:41169
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:40767
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:40743
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:41169
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:40831
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:41169
callCallback    @   bundle.js:58478
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   bundle.js:58527
invokeGuardedCallback   @   bundle.js:58587
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   bundle.js:58602
executeDispatch @   bundle.js:62837
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   bundle.js:62869
processDispatchQueue    @   bundle.js:62882
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   bundle.js:62893
(anonymous) @   bundle.js:63104
batchedEventUpdates$1   @   bundle.js:76789
batchedEventUpdates @   bundle.js:58276
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   bundle.js:63103
attemptToDispatchEvent  @   bundle.js:60586
dispatchEvent   @   bundle.js:60504
unstable_runWithPriority    @   bundle.js:89827
runWithPriority$1   @   bundle.js:65884
discreteUpdates$1   @   bundle.js:76806
discreteUpdates @   bundle.js:58288
dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

Comment: Wrap everything in a try catch block and log the error, i think you are not catching all the exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It turned ot that since I was posting data, it took the previous values and corresponded with the random id generated which doesn't change in the for loop so data.id stayed the same and the first time my data was posted but the second I got a validation error from the serve for unique key, so I just simply created an object inside the for loop and posted it:

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {

                    const workoutVolume = {
                        workout_id: data.id,
                        exercise_id: exercises.find(exercise => exercise.exercise_name === submittedExercises[i].toString()).id,
                        sets: submittedSets[i],
                        reps: submittedReps[i],
                        weight: submittedWeight[i],
                    }
                    requests.push(
                        fetch(`${BASE_URL}/workout-volume`, {
                            method: "POST",
                            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                            body: JSON.stringify(workoutVolume)
                        }))
                }
                Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
                    console.log('done')
                })
```